# Setting background color of UIView subclass doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I'm trying to change background color of one of my UIView subclasses. For some reason `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`doesn't do anything when I put it in my `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`method inside the view. The view is always black. I have also tried `self.myView.backgroundColor ...` from my view's controller, but that didn't work either. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

The relevant code looks like this:

```
[...]
@interface PaperView : UIView
[....]

[...]
@implementation PaperView
[...] 

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [...]
        // Initialization code        
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; // This doesn't do anything, the view is always black.
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: to initialise in UIVIew, you have to do **both** -initWithCoder:. and initWithFrame:  It's a real gotchya in iOS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indicative of the view not having a frame set to it.   I recommend setting a breakpoint in your `initWithFrame:` to verify that its being called.  If you were to call, say, `... = [UIView alloc] init]`, then that could be the source of your problem.

**EDIT**

If `initWithFrame:` is in fact being called, it's possible that the view is being covered by another view giving the appearance that it's not working (since you don't see it) or that the view itself is hidden.

Another way to troubleshoot is to override the backgroundColor property and set a breakpoint.  Find out what else, in the callstack, is changing the color.

Comment: I tried to add `NSLog(@"Hello");` inside the method and it did work.

Comment: Updated answer to include more troubleshooting tips.

Comment: You where right that the view was covered by another view. Silly mistake by me. But thanks!

Comment: If the view doesn't have a frame set to it, how would you solve that problem?

Comment: @Kerrm you would set a frame to it; otherwise, I wouldn't think you would need a background color.

Comment: This answer is, basically, wrong.  You use -initWithCoder:, not initWithFrame.

Answer (score 8):

If this view is being unarchived from a xib, you need to override `-initWithCoder:`. `-initWithFrame:` is only invoked if you are creating your view programmatically.

Answer (score 8):

I had this same problem. I hooked into `layoutSubviews()` and it worked ok:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `self.layer.backgroundColor` instead:

```
mySubclassedView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
```

Comment: this method is for ```UIViewController```

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov which method? If you mean `viewDidLoad()` method yes it is. I've written it just as an example. Every `UIView` has layer property which its `backgroundColor` can be changed.

Comment: the question is about `UIView` subclass and your answer is about `UIViewController` subclass. Downvoted because it doesn't answer the question

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov the answer had nothing to do with `UIViewController`. I had written that example to demonstrate how to use it. Now I reduced it to just one line. Use it to change background color of `UIView` subclass, if the code is not working (color is not changed) then downvote to show that this answer is useless. Otherwise it should not be downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

In what method do you call self.myView.backgroundColor?
Are you sure, that it's after viewDidLoad: ?
But, have no idea what is wrong with your first method.
Could you show more code?

Comment: Could you log background color after it was set?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you implement `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]` in `-viewDidLoad` method instead of `-initWithFrame`? Then try `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];` as well as `self.myView.backgroundColor` to see which works.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this *exact same problem*. The background color did not show even though I set the *correct frame* and set the background color to white in my custom init method, as well as in my `viewWillAppear` method. I also verified that nothing was covering it.

**Then I found the solution**: I set the background color in `viewDidAppear` instead, and all was fine:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
   self.view.frame = _viewFrame;
}
```

(The `_viewFrame` CGRect was passed in to my init method.)

Another option is to set it in `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`, depending on when and how exactly you want to set your background color.

To be entirely honest, I don't understand (yet) why setting the background color in `viewDidAppear` worked while it didn't work in the init method, and the code for setting it was identical in both places.

Hope this helps,

Erik

---

**UPDATE:** 
It does have something to do with view's **frame**. When I set my view's frame in my init method, then setting the background color in the viewDidAppear no longer has the desired effect. This is *even* the case if I set my view's frame *after* my view build method that creates the sub views. So the real mystery is: between the point where I am done creating my view and the point where it is displayed, *what in the view's life cycle is causing the view's frame to be reset to something that is incorrect?*

So, the answer really is: it will work as long as your frame is set correctly and your view is visible. Just check your view's frame throughout the view's lifecycle to make sure it's correct.

Tricky...

Comment: this method is for ```UIViewController```, the example from question is for ```UIView```